# C++ - safe pointers range?

Tags: c++, pointers

I know `NULL` (0x00000000) is a pointer to nothing because the OS doesn't allow the process to allocate any memory at this location. But if I use 0x00000001 (Magic number or code-pointer), is it safe to assume as well that the OS wont allow memory to be allocated here?
If so then until where is it safe to assume that?

Comment: I do not have understood a single word

Comment: @axis We use null because we want to point to nothing. But if I want to point to 1 to something like null. But a little different. It's ok too? If yes then where it stops? ... It's ok now?

Comment: So you want a pointer which is invalid, but in a different way then a NULL-pointer. From a design point of view this looks quite strange. It would be interessting to understand why you want to do this...

Comment: @ElektroKraut I need something very very fast. When I want to remove pointer from my array I want to just change his value and when I want to get index in this array I just need to search for `Empty cell`. But this cells can contain null BTW. and another here, I need the whole pointers because some reason :D.

Comment: I think your design seems questionable.  But the only way I can think of to safely do what you want, would be to actually allocate a singleton object of the type you want, and never actually use that object; but to use its address as your "magic address" that won't be equal to any other (newly created) objects.  Note that this means that your "magic address" will be a runtime variable, not a compile-time constant.

Comment: Searching for an empty cell sounds far slower than any performance hit you'd get by using a struct that contains both a pointer and a status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Standard** (first)

The Standard only guarantees that `0` is a sentinel value as far as pointers go. The underlying memory representation is no way guaranteed; it's implementation defined.

Using a pointer set to that sentinel value for anything else than reading the pointer state or writing a new state (which includes dereferencing or pointer arithmetic) is *undefined behavior*.

**Virtual Memory**

In the days of virtual memory (ie, each process gets its own memory space, independent from the others), a null pointer is most often indeed represented as 0 in the process memory space. I don't know of any other architectures actually, though I imagine that in mainframes it may not be so.

**Unix**

In the Unix world, it is typical to reserve all the address space below 0x8000 for null values. The memory is not allocated, really, it is just protected (ie, placed in a special mode), so that the OS will trigger a segmentation fault should you ever try to read it or write to it.

The idea of using such a range is that a null pointer is not necessarily used as is. For example if you use a `std::pair<int, int>* p = 0;` which is null, and call `p->second`, then the compiler will perform the arithmetic necessary to point to `second` (ie `+4` generally) and attempt to access the memory at `0x4` directly. The problem is obviously compounded by arrays.

In practice, this `0x8000` limit should be practical enough to detect most issues (and avoid memory corruption or others). In this case, this means that you avoid the *undefined behavior* and get a "proper" crash. However, should you be using a large array you could overshoot it, so it's not a silver bullet.

The particular limit of your implementation or compiler/runtime stack can be determined either through documentation or by successive trials. There might even be a way to tweak it.

Comment: Then what's the limit in windows\linux?

Comment: @DividedByZero: I don't know for Windows, don't program there. On Linux, it will depend on your distribution. You need to check on all the platforms and with all the toolchains you care about. That's what it means to be implementation defined. (It's probable that it will be `0x8000` on all mainstream Linux, but don't take my word for it)

Answer (score 2):

You should not assume anything about the actual values of pointers. Especially, the null pointer is *not* required to be represented by a zero address, even though the literal `0` does look like a zero.

Comment: Then you mean that there is a way that can be allocated memory at 0x00000000?

Comment: Why do you even care about allocating something at a specific address?

Comment: I don't care about that, I want to use another address like 0 to something else. But I care if the there can be allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

The only valid range is supposed to be range allocated to you by the OS.ANYTHING else should be denied by the OS.

An exception to that rule is the shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard doesn't "reserve" any pointer addresses other than zero (null).  So it is not safe to use 1 or any other value as a "magic" pointer value.  Of course, in practice, some implementations of c++ probably do not every use certain values.  But you don't get any guarantees from the language definition.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give a broad view about this:

1. you probably will never ever access the real memory addresses because of the multiple sandboxing mechanism that every modern OS has and puts in place.
2. What is a NULL pointer from the software viewpoint ? a NULL pointer is a pointer variable that stores a value that the programmer pick as a meaningfull value and this value is used as a label with the following meaning "this pointer goes nowhere". a NULL pointer does not point to 0x000000 by definition, the definition of a NULL pointer it's not about where that pointer will point to but the value of this macro called NULL and this value will be the value of this NULL pointer.
3. in C you can assume that `NULL == 0`, only in C NULL is a macro that defines NULL as an int that is equal to 0, in C++ you do not have this liberty
4. there are types, labels and values ( in better terms, representations of values not real values ) for every variables, at least for primitives values, the same is for the pointers, if you are speaking about void pointers you are speaking about pointers that contains a memory address ( just like any pointer ) and the only special thing about this pointers is that they need a cast in C++ to be decoded, safely and effectively; it's a big mistake if you think about `void*` as pointers that points to nowhere or to `0` or to `NULL` or to `0x0000000`

by the way, i still don't get your problem ...

Answer (score 0):

A modern OS is likely to reserve at least one page for NULL pointer. So 0x1 (or 0x4 if you want 32-bit alignment) is likely to work.

But remember this is not guaranteed by C/C++ language. You would have to rely on your OS and compiler for such behavior.

Further more, there's no guarantee about the actual value of the NULL pointer. It may or may not be all zeros. If it's not, your trick won't work at all.